# Blur function instead of mouseup function not working as desired

Tags: jquery

I have the [Demo Table](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/shape/TableEdit2.php) which I can click on the cell(td tag) and I can change the value  on it.direct php DataBase.
To do that I need to contain two **tags.1 - span. 2 - input.**
like the below.

```
<td class='Name'>
 <span id="spanName1" class="text" style="display: inline;"> Somevalue  </span>
 <input type="text" value="Somevalue" class="edittd" id="inputName1" style="display: none; ">   
</td>
```

To control the data inside the cell I use in jquery .**mouseup function.**
mouseup works but also makes trouble.
I need to replace it with blur function but when I try to replace mouseup with blur
the program does not work because, when I click on the cell I am able to enter the input tag and I can change the value but I am not successful in Leaving the tag/field by clicking out side the table, which alow me to update the DataBase
You can see the  [Demo with blur Here](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/shape/TableEdit3.php).
What do you advice me to do?

```
$(".edittd").mouseup(function() {
        return false;
    });
  //*************
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $('#span' + COLUME + ROW).show();
        $('#input'+ COLUME + ROW ).hide();
        VAL = $("#input" + COLUME + ROW).val();
        $("#span" + COLUME + ROW).html(VAL);

        if(STATUS != VAL){
            //******ajax code
                 //dataString = $.trim(this.value);
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                         dataType: 'html',
                         url: "./public/php/ajax.php",
                         data: 'COLUME='+COLUME+'&ROW='+ROW+'&VAL='+VAL, //{"dataString": dataString}
                             cache: false,
                             success: function(data)
                             {
                                $("#statuS").html(data);
                                }
                             });
                      //******end ajax
                      $('#statuS').removeClass('statuSnoChange')
                        .addClass('statuSChange');
                         $('#statuS').html('THERE IS CHANGE');
                         $('#tables').load('TableEdit2.php');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 //alert(DATASTRING+'status not true');
                 }
        });//End mouseup function
```

I change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var COLUMES,COLUME,VALUE,VAL,ROWS,ROW,STATUS,DATASTRING;
    $('td').click(function() {
        COLUME = $(this).attr('class');   
      });
//****************
    $('tr').click(function() {
        ROW = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#display_Colume_Raw').html(COLUME+ROW);
        $('#span' + COLUME + ROW).hide();
        $('#input'+ COLUME + ROW ).show();
      STATUS = $("#input" + COLUME + ROW).val();
    });
  //******************** 
    $(document).blur(function() {
        $('#span' + COLUME + ROW).show();
        $('#input'+ COLUME + ROW ).hide();
        VAL = $("#input" + COLUME + ROW).val();
        $("#span" + COLUME + ROW).html(VAL);

        if(STATUS != VAL){
            //******ajax code
                 //dataString = $.trim(this.value);
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                         dataType: 'html',
                         url: "./public/php/ajax.php",
                         data: 'COLUME='+COLUME+'&ROW='+ROW+'&VAL='+VAL, //{"dataString": dataString}
                             cache: false,
                             success: function(data)
                             {
                                $("#statuS").html(data);
                                }
                             });
                      //******end ajax
                      $('#statuS').removeClass('statuSnoChange')
                        .addClass('statuSChange');
                         $('#statuS').html('THERE IS CHANGE');
                         $('#tables').load('TableEdit2.php');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 //alert(DATASTRING+'status not true');
                 }
        });//End mouseup function
        $('#save').click (function(){
            var input1,input2,input3,input4="";
                input1 = $('#input1').attr('value');
                input2 = $('#input2').attr('value');
                input3 = $('#input3').attr('value');
                input4 = $('#input4').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./public/php/ajax.php",
                    data: "input1="+ input1 +"&input2="+ input2 +"&input3="+ input3 +"&input4="+ input4,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#statuS").html(data);
                        $('#tbl').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
                        $('#tables').load('TableEdit2.php');
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: is it really a question or your achievement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur event does not fire when a user clicks around the document.

To see when events fire, you can attach a logging function using your javascript console.
Paste these in your console:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){console.log('document.mouseup()')});
$(document).blur(function(){console.log('document.blur()')});
```

Then click around and see that blur will not fire unless you the whole document loses focus (and not an all browsers).

What kind of trouble was mouseup causing?

Comment: Hi,how can I found selution to mouseup Futile plz look here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/c6ABa/5/)

Comment: Your problem is that document.click() runs when you click in the <tr> as well (in Firefox, at least). Change that mouseup to click() and add "e.stopPropagation()" at the end of your tr click function (this will stop the event from bubbling up to the document click handler, which would undo what tr.click just did). You can also add .focus() to input1.show() because currently you need two clicks to get to editing the field. See: [link](http://http://jsfiddle.net/c6ABa/80/).